# What is the name of this font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I need to know the name of this font because I like the style of the integral and the sum

[image: I want this font]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The font is in the Times Roman family. Do you have access to the pdf file? If so, do look under File -> Properties -> Fonts to access the font-related information directly.

Comment: I tried with newtxmath but I didn't like the sum symbol

Comment: I did *not* claim that the `newtxmath` math font package was in use. There are many, many Times Roman clones out there. Anyway, do you have access to the pdf file?

Comment: Yes I have access

Comment: Do you know [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)?

Comment: @erika21148: run in a terminal `pdffonts <file>.pdf` and you'll get a list of the used fonts.

Comment: I fear that this is not even LaTeX, most likely, it's InDesign or a similar desktop publishing software used by publishing houses, may be it's `mathematical pi` or `math & technical`, etc. With all this number of Times clones available for use in LaTeX, it's a shame that a decent math font is not available yet in any of these clones. Even commercial ones like `mtpro2` aren't as good as those used internally by big publishing companies. There are new attempts like `stix2` but still not as good either.